# Can't sign my Cordova Android app with SDK 31

Tags: android, cordova, google-api, cordova-android

Trying to upgrade my Cordova app to Android API 31.  I can compile it fine but when I try to install a signed version on a device I get

```
 adb: failed to install xyzzy.apk: Failure      [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl2088675470.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]
```

I compile the code, use zipalign, apksigner (as I've done for a long time), and then use adb to install to a device.

I've tried both API 31 and 32.  I'm using cordova 10.0.0, cordova-android 11.0.0, Java 11, build-tools 31.0.0 and 32.0.0, min sdk version 22, gradle 7.6.  I've deleted the app from the device, run "./gradlew clean" many times.  I have not changed the signing key.  I downloaded fresh copies of the 20 or so plugins I use.

Ran "jarsigner -verify" and got a lot of output, appears to be signed correctly.

I can install an unsigned version to a device, but not a signed one.

Any advice?

Thanks,  Jon

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="23005" android:versionName="2.30.5" package="com.xyzzy.xyzzy" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver" />
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationReceiverActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:taskAffinity="" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/accent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.emailcomposer.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.Provider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/emailcomposer_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.localnotifications.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.util.AssetProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/localnotification_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver" />
        <activity android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickReceiver" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <receiver android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you share your androidManifest.xml? the error appears to be in there

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Now Cordova compiles produce .aab files, I need to use bundletools to sign the app and then unzip the .apks file to create the .apk file.